# excludeFilters in @ComponentScan vs exclude in @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot

New to spring boot.

While trying to exclude a bean from `@ComponentScan`, to my surprise found very flexible exclude option from `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

To my understanding, `@Configuration` is inheriting from `@Component`.

So,

1. Why I have to remove the configuration from `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and why not from `@ComponentScan`.
2. We have `ASSIGNABLE_TYPE/REGEX/etc`. in exclude. So why still we need `excludeFilters` from `@ComponentScan`.

Is there any restrictions over each other and is it bad approach if we switch between these exclusions?

Could someone clarify here.

Comment: Component scanning and auto-configuration are two completely separate mechanisms, each comprehensively documented. Exclusions apply to each mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

`@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` are used in different phases of initializing the spring application context.

1. `@ComponentScan` - used to scan for bean candidates, spring will search for various annotations like `@Component`, `@Configuration`, etc, and take bean candidates. This is a spring's feature.
2. `@EnableAutoConfiguration` - used to scan for auto-configuration candidates, spring will search for configurations marked for auto-configuration and from them load bean candidates. This is a spring boot's feature.

An auto-configuration candidate can be annotated with `@ComponentScan` to load bean candidates, but usually modules that are auto-configuration modules will be more precise and use `@Import` or special annotations. In your spring-boot project, you should have a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` that does both `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. This will trigger both features and do the following:

1. Load all bean candidates from your module that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`
2. Search for auto-configuration modules that are loaded in your classpath
3. Try to load auto-configuration modules
4. Try to load bean candidates from your auto-configuration modules

When you exclude something from `@ComponentScan`, it is excluded from the scope of the specific `@ComponentScan` annotation and process, wether if it is your module or an auto-configuration module you created.

When you exclude something from `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, you try to exclude an auto-configuration candidate. Also note that you can not exclude normal `@Configuration` using this annotation, only auto-configuration candidates.